# Allow access to S3 bucket to any user authenticated by AWS SSO

Tags: amazon-s3, single-sign-on

We've implemented AWS SSO authentication with ActiveDirectory, corporate wise, for all our users. We use multiple AWS sub-accounts, so that ActiveDirectory users can connect to different AWS sub-accounts with their AD credentials, according to the AD group association with AWS policies.
This all works pretty well, however, it is not clear to me, how to implement following authorization properly. Some of our accounts have S3 buckets which should be available for all the users  authenticated by the SSO, without regards of the user access rights.
What is the right way to organize that?